# Can someone explain the type of nested SOQL query below?

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am trying to understand how salesforce/soql works:

Here is a soql where I am trying to understand what is the type of a specific filed:

```
SELECT 
  Amount, 
  Id, 
  Name, 
  (
    SELECT 
      Quantity, 
      ListPrice,  
      PriceBookEntry.UnitPrice, 
      PricebookEntry.Name,  
      PricebookEntry.product2.Family 
    FROM OpportunityLineItems
  )
FROM Opportunity
```

To be more specific, is `PriceBookEntry` a filed name inside an object OpportunityLineItem whew the data type is not primitive (i.e., not string, integer, etc) and therefore it's necessary to use properties such as UnitPrice or Name?

In other words, in the case above the nested query related to only one table, correct?